# How to publish the artifacts at the end using maven-release plugin

Tags: maven-release-plugin, multi-module, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project. I'm using maven-release plugin to publish the artifact to maven repository. I'm using following command to do the above task.

```
mvn -B clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DautoVersionSubmodules=true '-DscmCommentPrefix=[maven-release-plugin]'
```

In one of the sub-module, i have a Unit test failure, but still i see the remaining modules are published to maven repo, except failed module.

Is there a way to publish all sub-modules only when the Unit tests for all modules pass?

Following is the maven pom configuration i have in Parent pom.xml.

> ```
> <plugin>
>           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>           <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
>           <version>2.5.3</version>
>           <configuration>
>               <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
>               <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
>               <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
>               <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
>               <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
>               <pushChanges>true</pushChanges>
>               <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
>               <preparationGoals>clean deploy -U -B</preparationGoals>
>               <goals>clean install</goals>
>               <arguments>-Prelease</arguments>
>           </configuration>
>       </plugin>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The maven-deploy-plugin has a command line option "-DdeployAtEnd=true" that will accomplish this.  But because maven-release-plugin runs the deploy command in its own instance of Maven, you have to pass it into this instance using the maven-release-plugin -Darguments option.

Overall, your command will look like this.

```
mvn -B clean release:clean release:prepare -Darguments=\"-DdeployAtEnd=true\" release:perform -DautoVersionSubmodules=true '-DscmCommentPrefix=[maven-release-plugin]
```