# What maven command can I use to revert deployments or "Builds?

Tags: maven

I have created pipelines which will clean, compile, test, & deploy the code every time we update it. But in case of a technical issue/or error I want to add a step which allows me to revert/rollback the "build" or deployment.

Is there a maven command that can be used to revert/rollback builds/deployments?

Comment: What do you mean with rolling back a build? There is no command as far as I know but there are plugins you can use in order to revert certain things.

Comment: Could you tell me which plugins can be used to revert certain things?

Comment: Depends on what you want to revert. It may not be possible for everything. The `maven-versions-plugin` has a `versions:revert` command to undo dependency updates etc

Comment: You may be able to save the state by creating a copy of the target directory (or similar) and rollback by restoring that...

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you just run `clean package`, then another `clean` will erase the results of `package`, but if you have run `install` or `deploy` the artifact is send to the local repository or remote repository. This cannot be "rolled back" by Maven.

Answer (score 0):

The [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html) has a [rollback goal](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/rollback-mojo.html) that rolls back the changes that it made to version control:

- version changes in POMs are reverted
- created tag is deleted
- created branch is deleted

However, this rollback does not delete files that were uploaded to the remote repository! If the remote repository does not allow artifacts with final versions to get deleted or modified, then you would end up with a problem, because your next attempt would fail to re-upload.

The Maven Release Plugin internally uses the [Maven Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/index.html) to upload files, and the latter has an experimental [deployAtEnd](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#deployAtEnd) feature. Unfortunately, I did not manage to get it to work for my build (using the suggestion from [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54243700/502240)) - I still had a build in which the Maven Release Plugin uploaded files before exiting with a failure.